# Help with JQuery XML

Tags: jquery, xml

I found this code but its not working... any suggestions the parsexml is never being called

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "menuitems.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: parseXml
  });
    // fourth example
    $("#black").treeview({
        persist: "location",
        collapsed: true
    });

});

var strMenu = "";
function parseXml(xml)

{
    alert();
  $(xml).find("Item").each(function()
  {
      if ($("#output").append($(this).attr("type") == "topic")) {
        strMenu += "<li><span>" + $("#output").append($(this).attr("name")) + "</span>";
      } else if ($("#output").append($(this).attr("type") == "link")) {
        strMenu += "<li><a href='" + $("#output").append($(this).attr("file")) + "'>" + $("#output").append($(this).attr("name")) + "</a></li>";
      }
  });
alert(strMenu); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "menuitems.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: parseXml
  });
```

to

```
 $.ajax({ 
        type: "GET",
        url: "menuitems.xml",
        success: function(xml){
          parseXml(xml);
        }
      });
```

and now it works

Comment: Wow... it should have worked your original way.  Sounds crazy, but it might if the function parseXml were declared above  $(document).ready() -- just a thought.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the line:

```
success: parseXml
```

to

```
success: parseXml(data)
```